# The second Selenium test doesn't work on Jenkins (click() problem)

Tags: selenium, jenkins

When I execute my tests on Jenkins, the first test is successfully executed but the second not and it's the same code (the same line is present in the both code). I initialize my driver, and when the test is done, I close my driver and then the second test is executed.

The test.ng file is:

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Create">
    <classes>
      <class name="X"/>
      <class name="Y"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="Release">
    <classes>
      <class name="X"/>
      <class name="Z"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

The code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("neo-navbar-collapse")).click();
```

The error message is:

```
initializeDriver(X)  Time elapsed: 16.445 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"neo-navbar-collapse"}
```

PS: X, Y, Z are hidden information

Thanks for help!